# How to identify regex bad characters in a long list of characters?

Tags: python, regex, perl

The goal is to port this Perl regex (from [here](https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/generic/mteval-v14.pl#L973)) into Python:

```
$norm_text =~ s/(\P{N})(\p{P})/$1 $2 /g;
```

First I've copied the `\p{P}` and `\P{N}` character array into a readable text file:

- [Number.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alvations/charguana/master/charguana/data/perluniprops/Number.txt)
- [Punctuation.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alvations/charguana/master/charguana/data/perluniprops/Punctuation.txt)

I.e.

```
import requests
from six import text_type

n_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alvations/charguana/master/charguana/data/perluniprops/Number.txt'
p_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alvations/charguana/master/charguana/data/perluniprops/Punctuation.txt'

NUMS = text_type(requests.get(n_url).content.decode('utf8'))
PUNCTS = text_type(requests.get(p_url).content.decode('utf8'))
```

But when I tried to compile the regex:

```
re.compile(u'([{n}])([{p}])'.format(n=NUMS, p=PUNCTS)
```

It throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/alvas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 233, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/Users/alvas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 301, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/Users/alvas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sre_compile.py", line 562, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/Users/alvas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 856, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, False)
  File "/Users/alvas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 415, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose))
  File "/Users/alvas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 763, in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose)
  File "/Users/alvas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 415, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose))
  File "/Users/alvas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 552, in _parse
    raise source.error(msg, len(this) + 1 + len(that))
sre_constants.error: bad character range ~-- at position 217 (line 1, column 218)
```

Looking around the problem seems to be that the dashes that are not escaped within the character sets, [Python regex bad character range.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28539253/python-regex-bad-character-range).

It looks like there's a range of dash like symbols in:

```
>>> NUMS[215:352]
'~----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
```

Then I moved the dashes characters to the front of the string but there's more bad characters:

```
>>> NUMS2 = re.escape(NUMS[215:352]) + NUMS[:215] + NUMS[352:]
>>> re.compile(u'([{n}])'.format(n=NUMS2))
```

[out]:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/alvas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 233, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/Users/alvas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 301, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/Users/alvas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sre_compile.py", line 562, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/Users/alvas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 856, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, False)
  File "/Users/alvas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 415, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose))
  File "/Users/alvas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 763, in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose)
  File "/Users/alvas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 415, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose))
  File "/Users/alvas/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 552, in _parse
    raise source.error(msg, len(this) + 1 + len(that))
sre_constants.error: bad character range ¬-- at position 502 (line 1, column 503)
```

So I moved more characters to the front:

```
>>> NUMS2 = re.escape(NUMS[215:352]) + NUMS[:215] + NUMS[352:]
>>> NUMS3 = re.escape(NUMS2[500:504]) + NUMS2[:500] + NUMS2[504:]
>>> re.compile(u'([{n}])'.format(n=NUMS3))
```

This seems to be an endless cycle of detecting what is a "bad character range" in a regex.

**Is there a way to automatically identify all "bad characters" in a regex and shift them to the front?**

Comment: All you need is to escape the `^`, `-`, `]` and ``\`` chars. Try `re.sub(r'[]^\\-]', r'\\\g<0>', NUMS)` and `re.sub(r'[]^\\-]', r'\\\g<0>', PUNCTS)` and then pass them to the `.format()` method.

Comment: It seems like the original NUMS has duplicates too =) @WiktorStribiżew the regex you provided worked.

Comment: First, `NUMS = ''.join(set(text_type(requests.get(n_url).content.decode('utf8')))`
, then 
`NUMS = re.sub(r'[]^\\-]', r'\\\g<0>', NUMS)`
And this works `re.compile(u'([{n}])'.format(n=NUMS))`

Comment: Yes, the lists you have seem to contain dupes, but that is something you can handle easily, yes, e.g. with `set()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main point here is that you need to escape the `^`, `-`, `]` and `\` chars inside a character class.

Use

```
NUMS = re.sub(r'[]^\\-]', r'\\\g<0>', NUMS)
PUNCTS = re.sub(r'[]^\\-]', r'\\\g<0>', PUNCTS)
rx = re.compile(u'([{n}])([{p}])'.format(n=NUMS, p=PUNCTS)
```

The `r'[]^\\-]'` pattern will match 1 char - `]`, `^`, `\` or `-` - and `r'\\\g<0>'` replacement will replace the match value with a `\` and the match value.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Wiktor!