# YOLO model training error- raise source.error(msg, len(this) + 1 + len(that)) sre_constants.error: bad character range 5-2 at position 72

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, yolo

I try to train pretrained darkflow YOLO model with additional annotated images. However when I start flow command and it enters training, it gives this error. Could somebody suggest what I should do? Thank you. 
P.S. attached picture with all outputs after training starts in the image.

[Training output I receive with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q4aY.png)

Comment: Welcome to the community. To make it easier to help you please include the code which causes the issue. Also please don't post pictures of text, just paste it into your question and indent it with 4 spaces (Theres a button to do that for you in the editor).

Comment: Take a look at this answer, may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28539253/python-regex-bad-character-range